# Simulate click on menu item in SWT

Tags: java, menu, swt

I want to simulate a click on a menu item but found no method. I'm thinking of something like doClick() of JMenu.

At the moment my very stupid solution looks like this:

```
private void performClick(MenuItem source, Event event) {
  source.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, event);
}
```

But maybe there's a better way to fire the event?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach. `Widget.notifyListeners` is public API and that's the obvious way to simulate an event in SWT. A click on a MenuItem is really nothing more than an SWT.Selection event.

Comment: BTW, in case you're doing this in the context of UI tests, you may also want to have a look at [SWTBot](https://github.com/eclipse/swtbot).

Answer (score 0):

A MenuItem in SWT can be controlled by the method

addSelectionListener(SelectionListener listener)

The SelectionListener provides the method

> public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {}

where you can include the desired functionality.

For a documentation to the Class Menu Item see:

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FMenuItem.html